# Implementation of Parallel.ForEach for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Because the TPL backport not only contains Parallel.* but also PLINQ, concurrent collections, etc, I will try to use this one.

Just for fun, I profiled both the TPL implementation and my own, in the very basic and naive test, mine was actually a little bit faster.

**Microsoft TPL backport:** 00:00:17.0673098
**My Implementation:** 00:00:16.9210535
Intel Q6600 (quad-core), 4GB of RAM, Win8.1(x64), VS2013 targetting .NET 3.5

The code is [here (github gist)](https://gist.github.com/0x53A/30f9c3005932db2c74b9), the colorful output of the Concurrency Visualizer is below:

[image]

This negligeable performance difference (in the best case) gets outweight by the many optimisations the .NET team put in for special cases.

**Question:**

To ease working with multithreaded code, I wanted to implement a version of `Parallel.ForEach` for .NET 3.5.

We are for the moment stuck with 3.5 and cannot upgrade.  We cannot use external libraries like TPL.

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33084/Poor-Man-s-Parallel-ForEach-Iterator) via Google, but this threw sporadic exceptions during runtime, and because I couldn't find another Version I decided to roll my own.

I did of course test it, but i am always a bit cautious with multithreaded code.

```
public class Parallel
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (items == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        var resetEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((i) =>
            {
                action((T)i);
                evt.Set();
            }, item);
            resetEvents.Add(evt);
        }

        foreach (var re in resetEvents)
            re.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could replace the foreach on resetEvents with `WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents.ToArray())`.  See [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(v=vs.110).aspx).  It even lets you provide a timeout if you need to support actions which could never terminate.

Comment: Unfortunately, WaitHandle.WaitAll only supports up to 64 items AND throws an Exception on a STA Thread...

Comment: Your wish is granted: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot use external libraries (i could, but it would be a big hassle)

Comment: The package Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5 1.0.2856 that Jessie referred to is published by Microsoft.  From the nuget page: "This backport was shipped with the Reactive Extensions (Rx) library up until v1.0.2856.0. It can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24940"

Comment: The NuGet package contains one assembly, System.Threading.dll, which is signed by Microsoft and has a PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (same as System.Workflow.Activities).  I guess you need to evaluate if the hassle of getting permission to use this 'external' library out weighs the hassle of writing your own.

Comment: Does the other version of `Parallel.ForEach` also wait until all tasks complete?

Comment: [This Microsoft guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) has a very good implementation of Parallel.ForEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    if (items == null)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
> ```

In the execution path where this exception is thrown, the reported argument name will not match the *actual* argument name. If this is the result of a *rename refactoring* (i.e. it's *the parameter formerly known as "enumerable"*), it's unfortunate, the string literal wasn't taken care of. That doesn't happen with ReShaper performing the refactoring, but if you're using the refactoring built into VS, I'm not sure it handles string literals; if you've *manually* "renamed" the argument, ...*next time, use refactor/rename*! ;)

Your implementation queues a work item for each item in `items`.

> #### [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx)
>
> *Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available.*

The interesting bit is about its *return value*:

> **Return Value**
>
> **Type**: `System.Boolean`
>
> **true** if the method is successfully
>   queued; `NotSupportedException` is thrown if the work item could not be
>   queued.

There's the slight possibility that thread pooling might not be supported on the platform code is running on (from what I gathered of reasons for this exception to be thrown), in which case the first iteration will throw a `NotSupportedException` that the `ForEach` code might not be expecting at all... but letting it bubble up might just be the best thing to do in this case.

---

If I correctly understand what's going on, you're essentially spawning a thread to run an `action`, for **each** `item` in `items`. This might not be as efficient as you'd think it is: there's only so many concurrent operations that can happen on a quad-core processor, and then there's overhead too; sometimes it's more efficient to simply run the tasks sequentially.

And that's what `Parallel.ForEach` does:

> #### [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> *Executes a foreach operation on an `IEnumerable` in which iterations **may** run in parallel.*

Thus, I'd use your implementation with care, and perhaps use a profiler and benchmark against a "normal" `foreach` for a given number of iterations, but then your dev environment *might* have different computing power than your test and/or production environments, so careful with benchmarks, too.

It might be simpler to use the Microsoft NuGet package [@JesseC.Slicer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/implementation-of-parallel-foreach/48834#comment85691_48804) and [@PhilBolduc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/implementation-of-parallel-foreach#comment85719_48804) mentioned in the comments...

Comment: Credit for point out the TaskParallelLibrary package goes to  @Jesse C. Slicer

Comment: The point of `ThreadPool` is that it *doesn't* spawn a new thread for each operation.